# Fast way to calculate Eigen of 2x2 matrix using a formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I found this site: http://people.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math21b2004/exhibits/2dmatrices/index.html

Which shows a very fast and simple way to get Eigen vectors for a 2x2 matrix. While harvard is quite respectable, I want to understand how this quick formula works and not take it on faith

Part 1 calculating the Eigen values is quite clear, they are using the characteristic polynomial to get the Eigen values.

Part 2, where they calculate the Eigen vectors is what I don't understand and have tried to prove but cannot.

I understand that that what matters with Eigen vectors is the ratio, not the value. For example, an Eigen value of 2, with vector 3, 4, I could have any other vector, example 6, 8, or 12, 16, etc... any scalar multiple.

In their example, given a matrix in the form a b c d, if b & c are zero, then the vectors are 1 0 and 0 1, which makes sense as you can scale these to any other size.

I don't understand the other two cases (when b=0, or c=0), or I presume the case when b & c are non-zero.

Can somebody offer an explanation or proof of this?

Comment: See the [*Trace Method*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#2.C3.972_matrices)

Comment: @Amzoti, nice reference.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: Thank you Andreas! Regards

Comment: The quadratic formula is actually wrong in the Harvard site. It should be L1 = (T + (T^2 - 4D)^1/2) / 2

Comment: The quadratic formula is actually correct on the Harvard site. It's just a different way of writing it.

Answer (score 24):

The Harvard class page isn't actually using the trace method, as that computes each eigenvector from the *other* eigenvalue(s).  It's just solving the equations directly. And since it took me way too long to realize that...

Given an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$, the associated eigenvector(s) are the vectors $\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$which satisfy $(\lambda I - A)\vec{v} = 0$.

So we have:

$$\begin{bmatrix} \lambda - a & -b \\ -c & \lambda - d \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}(\lambda - a)x - by \\ (\lambda - d)y - cx \end{bmatrix} = 0$$

This gives us two (equivalent) ratios for the vector elements:

$$y = \frac {\lambda - a} b x = \frac c {\lambda - d} x$$

Choosing $x$ to be the denominator of each fraction gives us the solutions on the web site:

$$\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix}b \\ \lambda - a \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}\lambda - d \\ c \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 5):

Computing the eigenvalues comes down to finding the roots of $\lambda^2 -(a+d)\lambda + (ad-bc) = 0$. That part you know already.

So if the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, then assume $c\neq 0$ and then the claim is that the eigenvectors are $v_i = (\lambda_i-d,c)$. Then 
$$Av = (a\lambda_i-ad + bc, c\lambda_i - cd + cd) = (a\lambda_i - (ad-bc),c\lambda_i),$$ 
and 
$$\lambda_iv = (\lambda_i^2 - d\lambda_i,c\lambda_i).$$
The last coordinates are clearly equal, and we know that $\lambda_i^2 -(a+d)\lambda_i + (ad-bc) = 0$, which implies $\lambda_i^2 - d\lambda_i = a\lambda_i - (ad-bc)$, so the first coordinates are equal too.

If $c=0$ but $b\neq 0$, then the math works out the same way for $v_i=(b,\lambda_i-a)$.

Comment: So - next..  In other ways that I have calculated the Eigen vectors I get other values.  For example: for (lambda=2), I might get the vector (3,4) - I get a different vector value, ie: (6,8).

Comment: Sorry, I did that wrong ... Eigen vectors are in the form c(a,b) where c is a constant. Thus if I come up with (2,-3) using this method, and (-4,6) using another method both vectors are valid... because what matters is the ratio of (a/b) must be identical. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Any multiple of an eigenvector $v$ is also an eigenvector, because $A(cv) = cAv = c\lambda v = \lambda (cv)$.